# Redirect to register page if not logged in and try to access restricted page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to restrict the access to a product on my woocommerce website.
If user are not login, I want to redirect them to register page.
I'm using this code but all my products redirect to register page :

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
    if (! is_user_logged_in()

&& (is_woocommerce() || is_cart() || is_single(1735) || is_checkout())
) {

   // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs

   wp_redirect( 'https://www.la-chaine-maconnique.fr/my-account/' );

   exit;
   }
}
 add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

To you think of Something  ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is redirecting from all products to the register page is that the `wp_redirect` function is running on all page that use a Woocommerce template as you use `is_woocommerce()`.

I think what you need is the following:

```
function reg_redirect(){
    if( is_product(1735) && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
       wp_redirect( 'https://www.la-chaine-maconnique.fr/my-account/' );
        exit(); 
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'reg_redirect');
```

Comment: Do you think I should use this code also for the cart and checkout ?

Comment: You can, it's just a matter of opinion really. Many sites let non logged in users go to the cart page and see an empty cart.  Possibly use it on the checkout though

Comment: This solution is correct, but the reason why isn't explained: the `||`s in the original IF statement means "or", which means it will run if any one of those things is true. The only change I'd make to this answer is `wp_redirect( site_url('my-account/') );` just in case in the future you change your domain name.

Comment: Yes, but he maybe also wanted to redirect if the logged in user tried to access the cart or checkout pages, in which case the OR conditions were the correct way to go, leaving the is_woocommerce() function as the incorrect part

Comment: I understand what you are explaining but all my products are still redirecting to "my account" and not just only the product 1735

Answer (score 0):

You can try to verify the operator is working properly!
You can change "&&" with "and", or just put one condition in the if statement: which means do the following:
(note that this will redirect all users, even the signed-in ones)

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
   if ( is_single(1735)) {

   // feel free t`enter code here`o customize the following line to suit your needs
   wp_redirect( 'https://www.la-chaine-maconnique.fr/my-account/' );
   exit;
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

If the above code works for only the single product you target, then experiment with your operates.
A better solution is that you avoid is_signle(), [it's reported](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-is_singlexxx-doesnt-work-resolved/) that is_single doesn't work properly with WooCommerce, you can try the following:

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
    global $post;
    if ($post->ID = '1735' and !is_user_logged_in()) {
        // whatever you try to do here for product id = 123 will work!
        wp_redirect( 'https://www.la-chaine-maconnique.fr/my-account/' );
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```