# PHP to redirect 1 post is applying on all my post

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like no redirect **not logged in** user who is trying to access a specific product, to `My Account` page to help them register (in WooCommerce).

I'm using the code below, but at present all the products redirect to `My account`:

```
function reg_redirect(){
   if( is_product(1735) && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
       wp_redirect( 'https://www.la-chaine-maconnique.fr/my-account/' );
       exit(); 
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'reg_redirect');
```

An idea what's wrong ?

Comment: Didn't you already [ask this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48923438/redirect-to-register-page-if-not-logged-in-and-try-to-access-restricted-page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `is_product()` doesn't accept a post ID as an argument like `is_single()` and similar functions do.

You could simply use `get_the_ID()`, though:

```
function reg_redirect(){
   if( 1735 == get_the_ID() && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
       wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
       exit(); 
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'reg_redirect');
```

Note that you should also use `get_permalink()` and `get_option()` together to get the URL of your account page, rather than 'hard-coding' it (passing it as a string).

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with woocommerce, but according to https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_product.html, I don't think is_product is the function you want. Try this.

```
global $product;
function reg_redirect(){
   $id = $product->get_id();
   if( $id == 1735 && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
       wp_redirect( 'https://www.la-chaine-maconnique.fr/my-account/' );
       exit(); 
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'reg_redirect');
```